# Batch File Wildcards

Tags: windows, wildcard, batch-processing

I want to generate a bat file for multiple tag processing and the command lines look like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\tools\tag.exe" -t Genre="%genre%" "%_folderpath%\%track%. %title%.%_extension%"
IF ERRORLEVEL==1 PAUSE
```

I can populate all variables automatically but can I replace the %title% variable with a wildcard?

Answer (score 0):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\tools\tag.exe" -t Genre="%genre%" "%_folderpath%\%track%. *.%_extension%"
IF ERRORLEVEL==1 PAUSE
```